# use substring and ternary operator linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

i want to show only 20 characters of contractname,how to do that in following situation?

```
OPM.Models.OPMLEntities obj = new OPM.Models.OPMLEntities();

var Contracts = obj.getUserContractss(UserID, p).ToList();
ViewBag.contracts = Contracts.OrderByDescending(s => s.contractId&&(s.contractName.Length>20?s.contractName.Substring(0, 20).Trim() + "..." : s.contractName));
```

Comment: The code you've given wouldn't even compile - what do you expect `s.contractId && (some string expression)` to do? And do you understand that you're just specifying the *ordering* at the moment? (I really don't think you want to be doing this in the ordering part of your code...)

Answer (score 1):

```
OPM.Models.OPMLEntities obj = new OPM.Models.OPMLEntities();

var Contracts = obj.getUserContractss(UserID, p).ToList();
ViewBag.contracts = Contracts.OrderByDescending(s => s.contractId)
    .Select(s.contractName.Length>20?s.contractName.Substring(0, 20).Trim() + "..." : s.contractName);
```